# The concept of an incomplete market

Tags: pricing, hedging, market

While skeeming the relevant literature and web-sites I noticed that mostly the concept of the incomplete market is reduced to the following statement

> "A market is incomplete if there are more sources of noise than
>   tradeable assets"

This might work well as a rule of thumb but does not really explain the underlying consequences (e.g. what it actually means for the market participants) - also it doesn't aid in visualizing understanding the concept.

I tried to find a comprehensive and easily accessible reference on the topic online but was unsuccessfull. Thus I thought qaunt SE is the perfect place to colaborate on one!

**Explain/Illustrate: What is an icomplete market in a quant finance sense ?**

- examples on how a hedges might not work
- explanation via Arrow-Debtreu
  securities and exchange of risk
- reading suggestions/literature references
- how can a market be completed (e.g. introduction of a volatility index that can be traded etc.)

Comment: A good reference is "Föllmer, H. and Schied, A. (2002). Stochastic Finance: An Introduction in Discrete
Time, de Gruyter Series in Mathematics 27, Berlin". Whether it is "easily accessible" or not is of course a matter of subjective taste. It covers the first two bullet points comprehensively.

Comment: why not write that as answer ;) - I will also add my own take on the subject later

Comment: I don't remember the exact source, but I think Duffie wrote a nice paper (maybe the original one?) on Arrow-Debreu securities and equilibria in an incomplete market.

Comment: @quasi I will do some digging ;)

Comment: @Probilitator: This is a link only reply, which are supposed to be provided in comments as per policy. I learned this the hard way :-) i.e. one of my answers got removed.

Comment: @gg nope this would be a literature reference reply ;) - those books aren't going anywhere. There a difference between just posting some links to the first pdf you find on the web and actually naming a relyable source. Finding good sources/material can take a while - thus by naming them you actually help a lot ;)

Comment: This question is exactly what I wanted to ask, but it seems that no one properly has answered so far :(.